# Load html with ajax and delegate on success to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page load menu.php is appended. Now  it needs to activate the function mmenu once it is loaded successfully.

```
$("nav#menu" ).load( "/v4/inc/menu.php" );  



$("nav#menu").mmenu({
        offCanvas   : {
            position    : "left",
            zposition   : "front"
        },
        counters: true
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the complete callback of load() so that your menu plugin is initialized after the html exists for it

```
$("nav#menu" ).load( "/v4/inc/menu.php", function(){
    /* the new html now exists */
    $(this).mmenu({
            offCanvas   : {
                position    : "left",
                zposition   : "front"
            },
            counters: true
    });
});
```

See **[load() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**